# Unable to Login to VMware vCenter server through Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmware-server, vcenter, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have installed Cloud Foundry in Windows 7 machine.I am trying to login to VMware vCenter server through Cloud Foundry CLI  by giving API endpoint as IP address of vCenter server.I am getting "Server error, status code: 404, error code: 0, message:". However I am able to ping successfully to  the vCenter server and make API calls through REST client.

```
c:\ cf login

c:\ API endpoint> http://xx.xx.xx.xx

  Invalid SSL Cert for xx.xx.xx.xx
  TIP: Use 'cf login --skip-ssl-validation' to continue with an insecure
  API     endpoint

c:\ cf login  --skip-ssl-validation  -a http://xx.xx.xx.xx

c:\ API endpoint: https://xx.xx.xx.xx

  FAILED
  Server error, status code: 404, error code: 0, message:
```

Cloud Foundry version :  6.12.1

Please help me in debugging the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API endpoint has the following structure:

```
https://api.MY_IP.xip.io
```